# Apache Server stops serving content shortly after restarting

Tags: apache, server, internal-server-error

I'm facing an issue with my Apache server where it runs fine for a brief period after restarting, but then stops serving content. To get it working again, I have to execute the following commands:

```
systemctl restart httpd
iptables -F
```

After executing these commands, my website is accessible again, but after a few seconds, it stops showing the content.

I'm not sure what could be causing this behavior. I checked the Apache error logs, but there are no relevant error messages. The server doesn't seem to crash; it just stops serving content.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or troubleshooting steps to identify the root cause and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that the firewall is involved?

Comment: @pierpy thank you very much for your comment! Actually, that's an older question, and it was already resolved back then. I'm currently optimizing my questions because my StackOverflow account has some restrictions. I have to optimize my questions to get more upvotes, I hope to be able to ask more questions in the future. Your support is greatly appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: Cool. I didn’t see the date! I was reading fresh content, and the system showed me your old question. Post a regular answer, if it’s resolved. You can do that